# TFS deploy to Azure Multiple Reserved Instance Websites - is the site unavailable during the deploy?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have a question about deploying to an Azure website and I hope someone can help.

Assuming I am running my large-ish website on Azure as a Reserved Mode with 3 instances for scale.
 We link up TFS publishing, so we can queue a build and automatically deploy to the server.

My question is: with multiple reserved instance servers, does the deploy do something clever behind the scenes to ensure the site is never down - such as deploying to one server at a time after removing it from the pool and then placing it back into the pool? 
 Or if the deploy takes a few minutes, are all three servers down at the same time?
 If so, what is best practice for deploying updates to a live Azure website server without bringing down the site - albeit briefly?

Background - we're in our R&D stage with Azure, with a plan to move our ecommerce site from in-house hosting to Azure. So far we've done a lot of testing with running on Cloud Services and like the easy way of publishing out to staging, and then being able to quickly flip from staging to release.
 However, we would prefer to use websites instead if possible as they eliminate some of the downsides of using Cloud services instead. We cannot afford to have our websites down during each publish though - even if it was for only a small amount of time.

Hope someone can help or point us in the right direction!

Thanks,

Richard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen Nir Mashkowski's TechEd video, it's a deep dive into how WAWS works. You can find it on Channel 9. In his session he talked about the storage and domain-resolution process each request goes to.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2012/AZR305

He discussed this on Web Camps TV, too, here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Internals-with-Nir-Mashkowski

The files are actually not replicated across each reserved instance. Rather, your files are *stored* into a drive in WAZ Storage, and those files then *served* from the instances. This is how the sites can easily be replicated if an instance has issues, becomes overloaded, or in the most typical case - when you want to scale out to multiple instances.

So when your code is published it really only *lands on* one drive, then served from the instances. Nir's talks does the process a much better job than my description, so check that out for more in-depth details.

Comment: Thanks brady, 
I appreciate the help and the links, I will check out those videos later. Even with this model it seems that there is no real answer for keeping site up during the short time it takes to do the physical publish. Not a huge amount of time I know, but in eCommerce it's important our sites don't go down.
Hopefully Microsoft may address this later..